# Use <T> in class properties declare in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class like this

```
public class Tbl
{
    public string Name {get; set}
    public anyClass Datasource {get; set;} //I don't know what to use there
}

//Usage:
List<anyClass> anyList = GetList(); // Assuming I had a list
Tbl Table = new Tbl();
Table.Name = "Table1";
Table.Datasource = anyList;
```

Here, my propblem is making the Datasource can accept any input Class. How can I declare the Datasource for Tbl class right way?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 11):

If it was `Tbl<T>`, you might choose to expose `IList<T>` as the `DataSource`:

```
public class Table<T>
{
    public string Name {get; set}
    public IList<T> DataSource {get; set;}
}
```

For non-generic data you *might* choose to use the non-generic `IList`; however, in the core framework it is fairly routine to use `object` as a `DataSource`, as this allows use of both `IList` and `IListSource` (an abstraction around obtaining a list).

Comment: I used that way but problem is when I declare another class
public class Db  
{  
    public List<Tbl<T>> Table {get; set;}  
}  
It cannot under stand T in this case. But I don't want to use that way  
public class Db<T>  
{  
    public List<Tbl<T>> Table {get; set;}  
}

Comment: @user402050 ; assuming the tables are all of different types (which seems sensible), how do you expect to have a list of them typed the same? It can't be done *quite* like that. So either use `IList`, or there *are* some alternatives involving an abstract `Tbl` and concrete `Tbl<T>` (but again, it'll be non-generic when accessed through `Tables`)

Answer (score 2):

You use the type `Object`:

```
public object Datasource { get; set; }
```

If you want to use generics to specify the type:

```
public class Tbl<T> {
  public string Name { get; set }
  public T Datasource { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Yes, but T could be any kind of collection, not limited to a single class or interface; the generic version of using Object. Of course, often you want the more limited option; IList<T> is more self documenting than just T.